# Ring homomorphism $\varphi : m\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z _{\frac{n}{m}}$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

This is what I have to prove:

The map $\varphi : m\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z _{\frac{n}{m}}$ where $m \mid n$ given by $\varphi(x) =\overline{\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)}$ is a (not necessarily unital) ring homomorphism iff $m=1$ or $m=n$.

The backward direction is clear to me. It is the forward direction which I have been unable to prove.

---

Here's my attempt:

Suppose that the given $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism. Then $\varphi (m^2)=\varphi (m)^2$, so, $\overline m =\overline 1$. Hence $\frac{n}{m} \mid m-1$.

Further assume that $m \ne n$. Let $p$ be any prime dividing $\frac{n}{m}$.

Then $p$ divides $n$, also, $p$ divides $m-1$. So $p$ cannot divide $m$.

---

I have not been able to complete. Hints will be appreciated!

Comment: dear ahK, what does $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{m}}$ stand for?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom The equivalence classes of $\mathbb Z$ modulo $n/m$.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Let $n=6$,$m=3$, then $\phi$ by definition is trivially additive. Then working $\mod 2$, $[1]=[3]$, so $\phi(9ab)=[3ab]=[ab]=\phi(3a)\phi(3b)$.

Comment: @Eric Your comment seems fine. The question which I posted was at least what the author of the textbook that I am reading thought to be true.